# How do I exclude certain service during development with Spring MVC

Tags: spring-mvc

I have the following service which send email each time a purchase made by customer

```
@Component
public class EmailerService extends JavaMailSenderImpl {

    public boolean sendEmail(String userFullName, String recipient, String subject, String content,String replyTo)
            throws AddressException, MessagingException {
        initJavaMailProps(replyTo);
        Message message = new MimeMessage(getSession());
        message.setFrom(new InternetAddress(senderEmailAddress));
        message.setRecipients(Message.RecipientType.TO,
                InternetAddress.parse(recipient));
        message.setSubject(subject);
        if (withGreeting())
            content = "Dear " + userFullName + ",\n\n"+content;
        if (withRegards())
            content += "\n\nBest Regards, \n\nDNA G2 Support";
        message.setText(content);
        Transport.send(message);
        return true;
    }
```

And on my XML configuration I have two `Spring profile` which is named "normal" and "cloud". Now I would like to add a new profile lets say "Development" and would like to "disable" this service during development. This is due to many emails are still being sent out during my local testing. What's the easiest way to achieve this ?

Comment: Not understanding what you are asking. Please provide some more code for fast help.

Comment: Specify please what do you mean when you say profile in xml configuration.

Comment: Profile refers to Spring Profile. Currently I use two different profile for  separating database location. Now I am thinking of using different profile to determine if a service should execute something or skip it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume you are talking about maven profiles when your refer to "normal" and "cloud".

1) add a property to your maven profile in pom.xml (notice that Development is false). For convenience the Development profile is the defaut profile also.  If you need to run another profile you can do so via `mvn package -P cloud`.

```
  <profiles>
    ...
    <profile>
      <id>normal</id>
      <properties>
        <profile.email.enabled>true</profile.email.enabled>
      </properties>
    </profile>
    ...
    <profile>
      <id>cloud</id>
      <properties>
        <profile.email.enabled>true</profile.email.enabled>
      </properties>
    </profile>
    ...
    <profile>
      <id>Development</id>
      <activation>
          <activeByDefault>true</activeByDefault>
      </activation>
      <properties>
        <profile.email.enabled>false</profile.email.enabled>
      </properties>
    </profile>
    ...
  </profiles>
```

2) You need to enable resource filtering so your can inject this variable into your maven build.  Here we are saying the all files in the /src/main/resources should be filtered with our maven properties.

```
<project>
  ...
  ...
  <build>
    ...
    <resources>
      <resource>
        <directory>src/main/resources</directory>
        <filtering>true</filtering>
      </resource>
      ...
    </resources>
    ...
  </build>
  ...
</project>
```

2)In one of your spring .property files (ie. environment.properties) add the following.  Here we are saying that the property email.enabled will use whatever is included in the maven profile.

```
email.enabled=$(profile.email.enabled);
```

3) Now in your email service add the following instance variable, this will inject the property from your .property file into the variable emailEnabled

```
@Value("email.enabled")
private boolean emailEnabled;
```

4)  Now you can do that check in the service

```
if (emailEnabled) {
  ...
}
```